# UIPickerView as inputView, but disallow direct editing

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uipickerview, uitextfielddelegate

So I have UIPickerView as inputView for one of my text fields.
It works perfectly: it slides up, as normal keyboard would, I can select an option and it will be populated in a text field.

The only problem is that I can directly edit the field, by typing into it.
How to disallow this behavior? So that even cursor doesn't show up?

I've tried the:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [self.datePick setHidden:NO];
    return NO;
}
```

but in this case picker stops to work completely - it doesn't appear.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField isEqual:self.birthdayF] || [textField isEqual:self.genderF])
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

so the cursor is still there, but user can't type anything in.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `textField.enabled = NO;` and place a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `textField` and listen to the tap to display your picker.

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad
  {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [textField addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
  }


- (void) handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
  {
 //do stuff
 //if you need the textField here 
   UITextField *text = (UITextField *)tap.view; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if([textField isEqual:selectedTextField])
         return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

say your textfield name is `pickerTextField` 
now in ViewDidLoad add following line

`self.pickerTextField.delegate = self`; (don't forget to conform `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol)

than implement following method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if([textField isEqual:pickerTextField])
    {
    [self.datePick setHidden:NO];
    return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```